# How to print an element the same way for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).on('click', '.printMe', function(){
    var printWindow = $('#printthis');
    var printSettings = $(
        '<style>'+
            '@media print{'+
                '@page{ margin: 0mm; }'+
                'html{ background-color: #FFF; margin: 0mm; }'+
                'body{'+
                    'padding: 20mm;'+
                '}'+
                'body > *{ display: none; }'+
                '#printthis{'+
                    'display: block;'+
                    'width: calc(100% - 15mm);'+
                    'border: 1px solid blue;'+
                '}'+
            '}'+
        '</style>'
    );
    printWindow.append(printSettings).append($('.editablearea').clone());
    window.print();
    printWindow.html('');
});
```

`#printthis` is located directly under the `body` tag and will be the only element visible when printing, so I clone the content in it. The page's margin is 0 to hide all the fluff added by the different browsers. I used the body's padding because the margin doesn't seem to work. As the code is now it will print more or less correctly with Chrome, but only because I've set `#printthis`' width to `calc(100% - 15mm)`, if I try with Firefox it needs to be simply `100%` or it will not fill the page correctly (which I think should be the correct behavior).

I haven't used `@page`'s size attribute, because it's not supported by all the browsers, but all the copy paper in my country is A4, while the print size clearly isn't, is there a way to also set the size of the document? I tried checking what onlyoffice does and they simply convert it to PDF and make the browser download it instead of printing in Firefox.

edit: the preview works correctly in jsfiddle and also looks correctly if I try to emulate css print in the website I'm working on in Chrome's devtools. The transition fix doesn't work.

edit2: the body had a min-width value that I didn't notice until now, so that's done. Now I only need the pages to be A4 for all browsers.

Comment: @BlueBockser I'm already using a normalizing stylesheet.

Comment: You might want to look into Template literals in ES6: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: @Adriano not supported by Internet Explorer.